# Is there a preset CSS class when shopping cart isn't empty?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

WooCommerce enables automatically `.logged-in` class when a user is logged in. This allows to create a page with different content without any PHP coding.

Is there something similar when the shopping cart is empty? I am NOT seeking any PHP solution. It should be solved only with a CSS class so I can hide/show parts of a page depending on the fact this CSS class does/does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need php for that... try this in your functions.php:

Detect if cart is empty and add class to body if is:

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_custom_class' );
function my_custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-emptycart-class';
    }

    return $classes;

}
```

Now you can use .my-emptycart-class in your CSS.

Comment: If my solution doesn't work: please, put a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45118800/12282455

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. It looks like the `if` condition where you check if the SC is empty cannot be executed there. An exception is thrown when I tried to save `functions.php`. I had to use the one you offered me the link. Thx for the link!

Comment: Okay, I was not sure I could calculate the number of products outside like that. I updated my code so that you could mark that my answer helped you.